# Confusion about Imagefield

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning Django as a beginner. Commonly speaking(documentation-wise), is Imagefield for photos? What field is then for the image files? (dmg for example). Thank you.

Comment: You probably just want FileField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Comment: Thank you for answering newbie question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageField` inherits all attributes and methods from `FileField`, but also validates that the uploaded object is a valid image using Pillow. It also has two additional optional arguments: `height_field` and `width_field` (these are auto-populated with the height and width of the image respectively, each time the model instance is saved).

Example:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='image_collection', height_field='image_height', width_field='image_width', max_length=1000)
    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```